# .htaccess url friendly rewrite issue: having errors when files and folder names are same

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site where I am trying to implement SEO friendly rewrite with an .htaccess file

My site have the following folder structure:

```
- root/
    - corporativo/
        - [more stuff...]
    - social/
        - [more stuff...]
    - index.php
    - corporativo.php
    - social.php
```

index.php handles all my sites functionality and routing. I am using GET variable 'cuerpo' to determine the section i.e. for example for social section I am using index.php?cuerpo=social.

One of the problems I found is that having social dir and social.php are conflicting with names and with the rewrite conditions.

Please suggest the right way to handle this situation.

Thank you very much!
Best Regards!

Comment: Could you please explain what sorts of conflicts you are seeing? It might be a problem with your routing in `index.php` and not necessarily related to your `.htaccess` rules...

Comment: Are you getting any information from this issue (i.e. error message), if so please provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `.htaccess` file, before rewrite rules one can use these two conditions -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # Not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # Not an actual directory
```

They dictate that the following rule will only apply if the requested filename or folder doesn't really exist.  It is used so that a browser will still be able to access resources without them having to be routed.

<sub>I'm not 100% sure that this is your problem though. More likely it is an issue with your routing in `index.php`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct flags in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] #Not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC] #Not a dir
```

*EDIT:*
Lix makes a good point - if you are on a Unix, Linux, etc. you may not want to use [NC], however, if you are in Windows, for example, you would want to use [NC]

Comment: Depending on the server's OS, if this actually functioned (and I'm not sure it would), then it could potentially cause problems. On unix systems, there **is** case sensitivity in file names where as on windows system, AFAIK there isn't.