# .htaccess rewrite in the case of directories having the same name as php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Suppose I have these files/folders:

```
index.php
A.php
B.php
/A
  E.php
/B
  F.php
C.php
/D
```

Suppose I access the pages via /site/.
I want to rewrite the URLs to perform these tasks:

```
/site/A -> /site/A.php
/site/B -> /site/B.php
/site/index -> /site/index.php
/site/A/F?id=828 -> /site/A/F.php?id=828
```

I would also like to mask the '.php' extension upon completion. How does one rewrite URL in this manner?
I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084559/htaccess-url-friendly-rewrite-issue-having-errors-when-files-and-folder-names) but I still don't really understand how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The question that you link did a check to make sure the request isn't an existing file or directory. But that breaks because you have a directory `/A/` and `/B/`. So you just need to check if there exists a `/A.php` and `/B.php`.

Comment: The code that you gave me didn't work for some reason.
Instead I used this code:
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (A|B)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

How can I change the line for (A|B) to encompass all files/folders that possibly have the same names?